# Not manually loop through every array in JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like below. I need to find the value of `name`, so in this case it will be "Mark". I don't know how deep the object is in the JSON structure or how many of them in the JSON. There could be multiple in different levels. I know I can just loop through every value object to look for it. Is there an easier way?

```
{
  "person": {
    "value": [
      {
        "type": "RANGE",
        "value": {
          "to": "2019-11-05T05:59:59.999Z",
          "from": "1900-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "field": "published",
        "include": true
      },
      {
        "type": "AND",
        "value": [
          {
            "type": "OR",
            "value": [
              {
                "type": "AND",
                "value": [
                  {
                    "type": "OR",
                    "include": true,
                    "value": [
                      {
                        "type": "MATCH",
                        "value": "Mark",
                        "field": "name",
                        "include": true
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "MATCH",
            "value": "37",
            "field": "age",
            "include": true
          }
        ],
        "include": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple recursive way of finding "Mark":

```
function runThroughObject(object) {
  for (const key in object) {
    const value = object[key]

    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      runThroughObject(value)
    }
    else if (value === 'name') {
      console.log(object.value)
    }
  }
}
```

This is the whole working snippet:

```js
const data = {
  "person": {
    "value": [
      {
        "type": "RANGE",
        "value": {
          "to": "2019-11-05T05:59:59.999Z",
          "from": "1900-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "field": "published",
        "include": true
      },
      {
        "type": "AND",
        "value": [
          {
            "type": "OR",
            "value": [{
              "type": "AND",
              "value": [{
                "type": "OR",
                "include": true,
                "value": [{
                  "type": "MATCH",
                  "value": "Mark",
                  "field": "name",
                  "include": true
                }]
              }]
            }]
          },
          {
            "type": "MATCH",
            "value": "37",
            "field": "age",
            "include": true
          }
        ],
        "include": true
      }
    ]
  }
}

function runThroughObject(object) {
  for (const key in object) {
    const value = object[key]

    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      runThroughObject(value)
    }
    else if (value === 'name') {
      console.log(object.value)
    }
  }
}

runThroughObject(data)
```